# how to convert continuous signals into discrete signals / signal power

Tags: discrete-signals, continuous-signals

[image]

I've just started learning about continuous and discrete signals. I don't really understand how to convert continuous signals into discrete signals especially since there are no values given.

Comment: Hello NoobEE and welcome to DSP SE. You have to find the period of the signal $x[n]$ first and then find out how many $\Delta t$ fit into it. Then you replace the $t$ inside the $\sin$ with the appropriate $\Delta t$s and find the values at the samples time "instants". Then you use the power formula to calculate the power.

Comment: Have you learned about the sampling theorem and the Nyquist criteria? That would definitely be the place to start